# Async export of redis client in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

The following code constructs a redis client and exports. I am fetching the redis password from vault secret management service and that call is a promise/async. The code doesnt wait for that call and it exports the redis client before async call completes. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any idea?

```
import redis from 'redis';
import bluebird from 'bluebird';
import logger from '../logger';
import srvconf from '../srvconf';
import { getVaultSecret } from '../services/vault.service';

const vaultConfig = srvconf.get('vault');

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);

let redisUrl = '';
const maskRedisUrl = (url) => url.replace(/password=.*/, 'password=*****');
const setRedisUrl = (host, port, pw) => { 
  const pwstring = pw ? `?password=${pw}` : '';
  const url = `redis://${host}:${port}${pwstring}`;
  console.log(`Setting redis_url to '${maskRedisUrl(url)}'`);
  return url;
}

if (vaultConfig.use_vault) {
  (async () => {
    const secret = await getVaultSecret(`${vaultConfig.redis.secrets_path + vaultConfig.redis.key}`)
    redisUrl = setRedisUrl(srvconf.get('redis_host'), srvconf.get('redis_port'), secret.PASSWORD);  
  })().catch(err => console.log(err));
} else {
  if (!srvconf.get('redis_url')) {
    redisUrl = setRedisUrl(srvconf.get('redis_host'), srvconf.get('redis_port'), srvconf.get('redis_password'));;
  } else {
    redisUrl = srvconf.get('redis_url');
    console.log(`Found redis_url ${maskRedisUrl(redisUrl)}`);
  }
}

const options = redisUrl
  ? { url: redisUrl }
  : {};

const redisClient = redis.createClient(options);

redisClient.on('error', err => {
  logger.error(err);
});

export default redisClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `(async () => {...})()` returns a `Promise` and you are not `await`ing it at the top-level, so the script continues to run past that line, sets `options = {}` and returns the `redisClient`.

What you need is a [top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) which is enabled by default in [`Node versions >= 14.8.0`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.8.0/). However, if your project uses a version older than that, there is a workaround as shown below.

**Please note that the below code is NOT tested since I do not have the same project setup locally.**

#### Module

```js
import redis from "redis";
import bluebird from "bluebird";
import logger from "../logger";
import srvconf from "../srvconf";
import { getVaultSecret } from "../services/vault.service";

const vaultConfig = srvconf.get("vault");

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);

let redisUrl = "";
let redisClient = null;

const initRedisClient = () => {
  const options = redisUrl ? { url: redisUrl } : {};

  redisClient = redis.createClient(options);

  redisClient.on("error", (err) => {
    logger.error(err);
  });
};

const maskRedisUrl = (url) => url.replace(/password=.*/, "password=*****");
const setRedisUrl = (host, port, pw) => {
  const pwstring = pw ? `?password=${pw}` : "";
  const url = `redis://${host}:${port}${pwstring}`;
  console.log(`Setting redis_url to '${maskRedisUrl(url)}'`);
  return url;
};

(async () => {
  if (vaultConfig.use_vault) {
    try {
      const secret = await getVaultSecret(
        `${vaultConfig.redis.secrets_path + vaultConfig.redis.key}`
      );
      redisUrl = setRedisUrl(
        srvconf.get("redis_host"),
        srvconf.get("redis_port"),
        secret.PASSWORD
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } else {
    if (!srvconf.get("redis_url")) {
      redisUrl = setRedisUrl(
        srvconf.get("redis_host"),
        srvconf.get("redis_port"),
        srvconf.get("redis_password")
      );
    } else {
      redisUrl = srvconf.get("redis_url");
      console.log(`Found redis_url ${maskRedisUrl(redisUrl)}`);
    }
  }
  // Initialize Redis client after vault secrets are loaded
  initRedisClient();
})();

export default redisClient;
```

#### Usage

At all places where you import and use the client, you always need to check if it is actually initialized successfully, and throw (and catch) a well defined error if it is not.

```js
const redisClient = require("path/to/module");
...
if (redisClient) {
  // Use it
} else {
  throw new RedisClientNotInitializedError();
}
...
```